# What is the purpose of the fast appearing screens?

Tags: hamatora

Several fast appearing/disappearing screens are featured, during the episodes of the series. They stay on screen for one second or so, and appear out of the blue. This makes them basically impossible to read/understand, unless the viewer pauses the video.

[image: One of episode 4's fast appearing screens]

So my question is, are they supposed to be fully understood? If so, is the viewer really supposed to pause the video every time a screen like this appears?
Or are they supposed to be, maybe, only partially understood, and should we carry on with the episode even if we couldn't read/understand everything?
Or are they really of no importance, and just used to produce some kind of visual effect? In this case, is the content of the screens of little or no importance?

Comment: maybe relevant: [there is a similar question on the monogatari series](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/what-do-the-black-and-red-scenes-mean)

Comment: I heard its for marketing reasons. As it airs on tv, you cant see it, get curious, buy the dvd. But couldnt find any source confirming it thou.

Comment: With the exception of Monogatari, these scenes/frames as I've come across them usually have little enough text to be able to be read quickly. My guess would be that it's for a visual gag or just to add a bit to a scene or something. If there is a bunch of text, I'd say it's more to give the impression of something that's overwhelming. Monogatari, of course, is the exception to this, as the question linked above shows.