# What is the Japanese term for the CGDCT tag/genre?

Tags: japanese-language, terminology

What is the genre or tag in Japanese terms for CGDCT? (Cute Girls Doing Cute Things for those that are not aware)

Comment: Possibly related: [What does 'moe' mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/894/2516)

Comment: @AkiTanaka is CGDCT filed under moe in Japan?

Comment: I don't know if there's a good source for anime genres in Japanese, one that focuses on fan language rather than industry terms. There is definite overlap between CGDCT and both moe and iyashikei but neither is a perfect equivalent.

Comment: Looking at [this list](https://www.fandomspot.com/best-cgdct-anime/), I don't think there is a genre (in Japanese categorization) that is completely matches CGDCT, but moe should be largely overlapping. Another word is [日常系](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%97%A5%E5%B8%B8%E7%B3%BB) (Nichijo-kei), literally 'daily-life type'.

Comment: @sundowner I guess it really is just either moe or slice of life then

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes people say 'girls doing activities typically done by middle aged guys'  -  女子高生などの美少女に、おっさんの趣味をやらせる作品一覧  https://areablue.jp/2022/08/07/post-24632/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of the Japanese having a word for this.

It's overlapping a fair bit with `healing` or in Japanese Iyashikei `癒し系 ( いやしけい )`.
But it is not the same thing.

Not sure about today, but years ago when `cute girls doing cute things` was first used (around 2008, as far as I remember), it wasn't really to categorize anime. It was to make fun of them. For example "does this anime have a story or is it just cute girls doing cute things?".

In that sense the origin was a lot closer to healing than what the literal meaning of the phrase describes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and interesting that it was used to make fun of that certain type of anime when nowadays, people actively seek it

Comment: @user9564371 some people liked this genre back then, too. But the phrase originated from the one's that didn't care for it. People who appreciated it used healing or moe. The others called it moeblob and cute girls doing cute things.